# Lying to prevent mass hysteria?

Tags: society, government, conspiracy

Say a huge asteroid came along, around the size of the one that wiped out the dinosaurs. It was unnoticed for quite a while, similar to the 2018 GE3. Then somebody saw it, and scientists calculated that it was going to crash into the Earth, within the next few days.

Would it be plausible that the government wouldn't tell the public, to avoid mass hysteria, and instead all of the government officials and important people would be transported to underground facilities where they would be safe, while the public was left to fend for itself?

Comment: Note "the government" - we don't have one government on Earth, but we do have lots of competing governments and they're going to notice this event (and the mystery building programs) and very soon everyone will know.

Comment: Read the short story One for the Road by Gardner Dozois, with an amusing discussion of reactions to imminent, unavoidable doom.

Comment: What I am actually astounded is the upvotes this question has... maybe because its a conspiracy in itself?

Answer (score 8):

## No

> within the next few days [...] all of the government officials and important people would be transported to underground facilities where they would be safe, while the public was left to fend for itself?

Ok, several flaws in your thinking here...

1. You assume that "the government and all important people" are a separate entity from "the public". They are not. Our government officials, our scientists, our specialists, our thinkers and so on **are** the public. You assume that they are entirely selfish and will just ditch everyone else to save their own skin. This is not just flawed but also a very horrific thing to assume about people.
2. You assume that all government officials and "important people" all over the world will be of one mind in this. They will not be.
3. You assume that these people have everything set up and can just dive right into these "underground facilities" on a moment's notice, and that these facilities have the capacity to sustain these "important people" for a very long time. This is not so.
4. You assume that this secret will not leak simply because these government and officials are of one mind that just lying about it will be universally considered the best course of action; and that this lie is sufficient to just let tens to hundreds of thousands of people — all high profile persons that have eyes on them — drop everything they are doing and scramble for the shelters... **and not have anyone else notice**.

> — Oi... **every** politician and high profile person in a position of influence did not show up for work today. What's up with that?!
>
> — Well it's because [the lie].
>
> — Oh... well that makes sense, I will just stop asking questions about this unprecedented, highly irregular and generally weird occurrence then.

Considering that a person holding the most powerful office in the western world could not even keep a lid on having sex on the job, in a conspiracy involving only themselves and their sex partner... there is no way in hell that this will not leak.

In conclusion: **there is no way that you as an author can make this scenario plausible.** Even conspiracy nutters from The Weird Part Of The Internet will go "Whoa... no way... that is just too friggin' unrealistic".

Answer (score 7):

Once upon a time there was a government who locked a bunch of the brightest minds of the times into a city isolated in the desert, and managed to build an atomic bomb.

Despite all the precaution, the secret on how to build an atomic bomb was leaked, and the other side of the wall got the bomb, too.

Now, in your case, any government can decide to not say a word on the incoming danger, but cannot forbid the citizens to look up in the sky. Actually there are more amateurs looking at the sky than professional astronomers, so trying to keep this secret is like trying to carry sand with a fork.

Answer (score 3):

Yes and no.  It's plausible that silence or denial would be the official position, but it's not plausible that it would be believed.  With so little time before the impact, that must mean the asteroid is very close.  An asteroid that big and that near would be visible to every astronomer, amateur and professional, on Earth.  Any one of them could do the math to prove it was on a collision course.  Further, have you ever known the government to be able to keep a secret?  Especially one as juicy as Armageddon?

Answer (score 3):

**Six Degrees of Kevin Bacon says no**

There are too many people involved to keep this a secret.  It isn't just all the people deemed "too important".  Everyone who is on the 'important' list will be trying to get their family and friends also onto the list.  What are those new people going to do when they find out what this list means?  The same thing.  This means the list of evacuees will grow so big so quickly that it will be impossible to keep quiet.  The story will spread like wildfire just from this.

Two things will happen to doom this plan to failure.

1) Sooner or later someone will get upset that someone they care about isn't on the list, and will say 'damn the torpedoes full speed ahead' and spill the beans.  This might be someone important, but it probably be a low-level grunt who nonetheless needs to know, because they are an electrician wiring up the secret underground bunker or something.

No, you can't kill all of those people.  There are far too many and it will attract *way* too much attention.  And that means now you have to bring them into your little group of evacuees.

2) Too many people will be mysteriously disappearing to keep it covered up.  When word gets out that all the family and friends of the rich and powerful are disappearing (and it will), the panic that will ensue will be *worse* because it will be unexplained and because it will look like the elite stabbing everyone else in the back (because, uh, that's what it is).

Comment: +1 for referencing 6DoKB, and doing so in a relevant manner. :)

Answer (score 1):

The government is capable of keeping many secrets.  My personal favorite quote regarding keeping scary things secret comes from the movie Broken Arrow:

> Giles Prentice: A Broken what?
>
> Secretary Baird: Broken Arrow. It's a Class 4 Strategic Theatre Emergency. It's what we call it when we lose a nuclear weapon.
>
> Giles Prentice: I don't know what's scarier, losing nuclear weapons, or that it happens so often there's actually a term for it.

However, to answer your specific question, I think it's highly unlikely the government would keep this secret in this way.  Why?  Because its an enormously difficult secret to keep if you bring a large option of the government with you, and its a rather short sighted secret to keep if you only keep the political elite alive.  How badly do you want to cower in an underground bunker eating canned beans while the population of the planet gets reduced to 30?  What's your game plan?  Did you really just plan to cower, or were you thinking ahead beyond the cowering.  It would take a very particular psychological profile to want to go down this route, and it is statistically unlikely that all of your political elite will all think this way.

Answer (score 1):

All governments an all people having access to data agree at once that the will not tell anyone?
Scientist don't care about government or earth, the ones looking in the sky are thinking in terms of light-years and billions and billions of years. They get a hard on just thinking they will be the first to tell everyone that earth is going Kaboom!

Also they just may be one government that know they don't have asteroid-bunkers so it's better to tell people they can have unprotected sex and consume excessive amounts of alcohol and unhealthy food.